# convert ansible list of dictionariest to a list by value (in ansbile task)

Tags: python, ansible, jinja2

is there any way to convert list of dicts to list with values from one key from all dicts? (in ansible task) 
input:

```
[{'a':1, 'b': it}, {'a':2, 'b': ti}]
```

output

```
[1,2]
```

Comment: тут говорят руским языка

Answer (score 1):

Это можно сделать с помощью json_query

```
debug: msg="{{ mydict | jsonquery(myquery) }}"
vars:
 myquery: "[*].needed_key"
```